# CUDA kernel automatically recall kernel to finish vector addition. Why?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am just beginning to play with CUDA so I tried out a textbook vector addition code. However, when I specify kernel calls to only add the first half of vector, the second half also gets added! This behavior stops when I include some thrust library header.

I am totally confused. Please see the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

__global__ void VecAdd(float *d_dataA, float *d_dataB, float *d_resultC)
{
    //printf("gridDim.x is %d \n",gridDim.x);
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;    
//  printf("tid is %d \n",tid);
    d_resultC[tid] = d_dataA[tid] + d_dataB[tid];
}

int main() 
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 8*1024;
    const int ARRAY_BYTES = ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float);

    float *h_dataA, *h_dataB, *h_resultC;
    float *d_dataA, *d_dataB, *d_resultC;

    h_dataA     = (float *)malloc(ARRAY_BYTES);
    h_dataB     = (float *)malloc(ARRAY_BYTES);
    h_resultC   = (float *)malloc(ARRAY_BYTES);

    for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++){
        h_dataA[i]=i+1;
        h_dataB[i]=2*(i+1);
    };

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_dataA,ARRAY_BYTES);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_dataB,ARRAY_BYTES);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_resultC,ARRAY_BYTES);

    cudaMemcpy(d_dataA, h_dataA,ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_dataB, h_dataB,ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        cout << h_resultC[0] << endl;
        cout << h_resultC[ARRAY_SIZE-1] << endl;

    dim3 dimBlock(ARRAY_SIZE/8,1,1);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1,1);

    VecAdd<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_dataA, d_dataB, d_resultC);

        cout << h_resultC[0] << endl;
        cout << h_resultC[ARRAY_SIZE-1] << endl;

        cudaMemcpy(h_resultC,d_resultC ,ARRAY_BYTES,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cout << h_resultC[0] << endl;
        cout << h_resultC[ARRAY_SIZE-1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are launching enough threads to do only 1/8th of the work not 1/2.   It is possible that if you added the whole vector before adding part of the vector, the old results may be read. Try using random data that is seeded based on time to see if it is doing exactly what you think it is doing.

Comment: I agree that only 1/8 threads are being called, but it doesn't seem obvious to me as to how all the data would get added correctly with just 1/8 threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you launched it first with ARRAY_SIZE threads and then with the half of them? (or 1/8)

You are not initializing d_resultC, so it's probably that d_resultC has the result of the previous executions. That would explain that behavior, but maybe it doesn't.

Add a cudaMemset over d_result_C and tell us what happens.

Comment: Thanks your reply! I tried cudaMemset over d_resultC right before I call the kernel and fill it with all zeros. Somehow it still add the whole array although I only launch half the threads needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for sure why your kernel is processing more elements than expected. It's processing one elements per thread, so the number of elements processed definitely should be  blockDim.x*gridDim.x.

I want to point out though, that it's good practice to write kernels that use "grid stride loops" so they aren't so dependent on the block and thread count. The performance cost is negligible and if you are performance-sensitive, the blocking parameters are different for different GPUs.

http://cudahandbook.to/15QbFWx

So you should add a count parameter (the number of elements to process), then write something like:

```
__global__ void VecAdd(float *d_dataA, float *d_dataB, float *d_resultC, int N)
{
    for ( int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
              i < N;
              i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x ) {
        d_resultC[i] = d_dataA[i] + d_dataB[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As some guys mentioned above. This may be caused by the remain data from your previous run. You didn't free the memory you allocated may be the reason of this odd situation.
I think you should free the allocated arrays on the host using `free` and also free the memory on the GPU using `CudaFree`

Also I strongly recommend you to allocate the host memory using `CudaMallocHost` instead of `malloc` and free them at the end of the program by `CudaFreeHost`. This will give you fast copy. See here: [CudaMallocHost](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad.html)

Anyway, don't forget to free heap memory on C/C++ program, whether with CUDA or not.